# How to compute the value for `version made by` in zip header?

Tags: node.js, unzip, zip, adm-zip

I'm struggling to compute the **correct value** for `version made by` in [adm-zip](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip).

The [Zip Spec](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/blob/master/APPNOTE.md) is unclear in my opinion how to find the binary or int value to set an option (e.g. `Option 3 Unix`) to the depending 2 Bytes in the [central header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Central_directory_file_header).

The docs from adm-zip for the [header](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/wiki/ZipEntry#entryheader-buffer-header) setting does not help at all.

Mapping from the zip spec (4.4.2):

> 4.4.2.2 The current mappings are:
>
> ```
> 0 - MS-DOS and OS/2 (FAT / VFAT / FAT32 file systems)
> 1 - Amiga                     2 - OpenVMS
> 3 - UNIX                      4 - VM/CMS
> ```

I have found one possible solution by setting the `entry.header.made` property to `788`.

`(entry.header as any).made = 788;`

(This value was only found by importing a zip created by another zip util.)

**Can anyone explain how to compute this value `788` starting from the desired option 3?**

Or how to compute this value for another option e.g. `10 - Windows NTFS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short description:**

According to the [specification](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/blob/master/APPNOTE.md) the upper byte represents the OS which created the ZIP file. The lower byte is the version of the used ZIP specification.

**In your example:**

**788** = `0x0314`

*OS which created the ZIP file:*
`0x03` (Upper Byte): **UNIX**

> 4.4.2.1 The upper byte indicates the compatibility of the file
> attribute information.  If the external file attributes
> are compatible with MS-DOS and can be read by PKZIP for
> DOS version 2.04g then this value will be zero.  If these
> attributes are not compatible, then this value will
> identify the host system on which the attributes are
> compatible.  Software can use this information to determine
> the line record format for text files etc.

*ZIP specification version:*
`0x14` (Lower Byte): **Version 2.0**

`0x14 / 10` = **2** (Major version number)
`0x14 % 10` = **0** (Minor version number)

> 4.4.2.3 The lower byte indicates the ZIP specification version
> (the version of this document) supported by the software
> used to encode the file.  The value/10 indicates the major
> version number, and the value mod 10 is the minor version
> number.

**For Windows NTFS, the correct "version made by" value should be:**

`0x0A14` = **2580**

`0x0A` (Upper Byte): **Windows NTFS (Win32)**
`0x14` (Lower Byte): **Version 2.0**

Extract from [adm-zip source](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/blob/master/headers/entryHeader.js):

```
var _verMade = 0x14,
        _version = 0x0A,
        _flags = 0,
        _method = 0,
        _time = 0,
        _crc = 0,
        _compressedSize = 0,
        _size = 0,
        _fnameLen = 0,
        _extraLen = 0,

        _comLen = 0,
        _diskStart = 0,
        _inattr = 0,
        _attr = 0,
        _offset = 0;

    switch(process.platform){
        case 'win32':
            _verMade |= 0x0A00;
        case 'darwin':
            _verMade |= 0x1300;
        default:
            _verMade |= 0x0300;
    }
```

Here you can see, that the version **2.0** (`0x14`) from the ZIP specification is used and there is a simple OR with the left shifted OS which created the ZIP file.

**UPDATE:**
I wrote a few simple JavaScript example functions which returns the right value for `verMade` and which returns the OS, major and minor version number from `verMade`.

***Set version:***

```
function zip_version_set(os, spec_major, spec_minor)
{
    var ret = (parseInt(spec_major, 10) * 10) + parseInt(spec_minor, 10);
    
    switch (os) {
    case "dos":
        ret |= 0x0000;
        break;
    case "win32":
        ret |= 0x0A00;
        break;
    case "darwin":
        ret |= 0x1300;
        break;
    default:
        ret |= 0x0300;
    }
    
    return ret;
}
```

*Usage:*
*Argument* `os`:
Put her the OS string. Currently possible values are `dos` (MS-DOS), `win32` (Windows NTFS), `darwin` (OS X) and the default is `unix`.

*Argument* `spec_major`:
Put here the **major** version number from the used ZIP specification.

*Argument* `spec_minor`:
Put here the **minor** version number from the used ZIP specification.

*Return*:
Returns `verMade`.

***Get OS:***

```
function zip_version_get_os(verMade)
{
    var tmp;
    var ret;
    
    tmp = (verMade & 0xFF00) >> 8;
    
    switch (tmp) {
    case 0x00:
        ret = "dos";
        break;
    case 0x03:
        ret = "unix";
        break;
    case 0x0A:
        ret = "win32";
        break;
    case 0x13:
        ret = "darwin";
        break;
    default:
        ret = "unimplemented";
    }
    
    return ret;
}
```

*Usage:*
*Argument* `verMade`:
Put here the `verMade` value.

*Return:*
Returns the OS as string.

***Get major version number (ZIP specification):***

```
function zip_version_get_major(verMade)
{
    return ((verMade & 0xFF) / 10);
}
```

*Usage:*
*Argument* `verMade`:
Put here the `verMade` value.

*Return:*
Returns the major version from the used ZIP specification.

***Get minor version number (ZIP specification):***

```
function zip_version_get_minor(verMade)
{
    return ((verMade & 0xFF) % 10);
}
```

*Usage:*
*Argument* `verMade`:
Put here the `verMade` value.

*Return:*
Returns the minor version from the used ZIP specification.